# Docker files work with vscode and visual studio 2017

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, dockerfile

Hi I am working with a team that has both windows and macs as the development machines of choice.  We are creating a dotnetcore app that runs in a docker container. I am having all sorts of issues trying to run the app in a docker container using the DockerFile generated from visual studio 2017.  Has anyone had any luck with this? Those with visual studio 2017 want to use the features to work well while there are those that want to develop with vscode.

This is the Dockerfile.dev generated by Visual Studio 2017

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "magic-service.dll"]
```

On a mac I get an error while running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

which simple contains

```
version: '3'
services:
  magic-service:
    image: magic-service
    build:
      context: ./magic-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
```

The error recieved is

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder810701514/obj/Docker/publish: no
>   such file or directory

Comment: This may be because when Visual Studio runs the build it might be passing the build argument `source`. I don't work on windows much so can't confirm

Comment: Yes, the `source` is apparently something passed by Visual Studio at build. I have a similar issue where I want to figure out a good way to write a COPY command that works both for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Team services build definition. Or maybe there is a way to have multiple build definition? I'm learning too.